# Angular materials not applying theme to page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io). I want to theme my page using the prebuilt themes and aim to have it looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d31dv.jpg). However, the [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqpPt.jpg) still shows up in grey. How do I got about applying the themes?  I have added this

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

to the styles.css file.  I have tried doing `color="primary"` in my app.component.html but to no avail. The following is the app.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container color="primary" fullscreen>
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side">
    <p><button mat-button class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" color="primary">Home</button></p>
    <p><button mat-button class="nav-link" routerLink="/menu" routerLinkActive="active" color="primary">Menu</button></p>
</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content color="primary">
  <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button></p>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to styles.css file

```
  @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

in polyfills.ts add

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Comment: Seems like `import 'hammerjs';` was what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please document what's the difference between the OP's code and your code so that others understand what the difference is or understand the reasoning of your code?

Comment: import 'hammerjs'; fails and as mentioned before, author did not explain anything to why this is needed

Comment: From the docs:Angular Material, as of version 9, no longer requires HammerJS for any component. So this is no solution for Angular 9

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hack through this recently for Angluar 16.0.2:

```
ng new application --style=scss myApp
cd myApp
ng add @angular/material
<..snip>your other components here</snip>
```

then edit `myApp/app/src/styles.scss` and add

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```